# How to fade out a splash screen in react native?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I would like to make a fade out effect in my splash screen, because it disappears at once right now.

I create the splash screen here:

```
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    SplashScreen.show(this, R.style.SplashTheme, true);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  }

...

}
```

And I hide the splash screen here:

```
const App = () => {

  changeNavigationBarColor('white', true, true);

  // HERE
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      SplashScreen.hide();
    }, 3000);
  }, []);


  return (
     ...
  );
}

export default App;
```

I'm following this [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R8cl0v_tPog), that uses this [library](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen).

Answer (score 0):

There is no property like that in react-native-splash-screen. Simply you can't. But it supposes to fade out as I know. Maybe you can't see because of the emulator skipping some frames.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [this library](https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-bootsplash#usage) which has argument called `fade` when executing hide function.

Simply do,

```
RNBootSplash.hide({ fade: true }); // fade
```

Answer (score 0):

### Expo solution

If you are using expo, you can follow [this example](https://github.com/expo/examples/tree/master/with-splash-screen).

The main concept here is that when the default splash screen is hidden, you keep displaying a splash screen as a component at the same place (it's pretty easy to do).
From there you can do anything you would do with a regular component like fadeIn/Out, blur animations, scale...and so on.